# Should simply changing the Locale change decimal number notation in Java?

Tags: java, decimal, locale

Yes, I read through the various post with regards to this but their scenarios where a bit different and didn't explain what is going on in the background.

Lets say the following program is created in a country where decimal points use '.' notation but then executed in a country which uses ',' notation.

For example, 1.23 and 1,23 are technically the same number but with different notations.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.*;
class LocaleTestDecimal extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
static JTextField t;
static JFrame f;
static JButton b;
static JLabel l;
static JLabel localLabel;
LocaleTestDecimal()
{
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    f = new JFrame("Locale = " + locale.toString());
    l = new JLabel("nothing entered");
    
    b = new JButton("submit");
    LocaleTestDecimal te = new LocaleTestDecimal();
    b.addActionListener(te);
    t = new JTextField(16);
    //default value of 1.23
    t.setText(Double.toString(1.23));
    
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
    Number number = null;
    try {
        number = format.parse("1.23");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    double d = number.doubleValue();
    l.setText(Double.toString(number.doubleValue()));
    
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(t);
    p.add(b);
    p.add(l);
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.show();
}

// if the button is pressed
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String s = e.getActionCommand();
    if (s.equals("submit")) {
        // set the text of the label to the text of the field
        l.setText(t.getText());

        // set the text of field to blank
        t.setText(" ");
    }
}
}
```

The above code runs fine and as expected when my Locale is set to English.

After changing my Windows Region and Format to Italy.

[image]

And changed my Eclipse VM arguments

[image]

The numbers still use the '.' notation for numbers. Even using the NumberFormat didn't seem to change the value on the JFrame.

The title of the JFrame contains the locale which confirms it is Italy.

[image]

**Question 1:** 
Why am I not seeing numbers using the ',' notation?

**Question 2:** 
As these numbers expected to dynamically change simply based on the Locale set?

Comment: The `Double.toString()` method does not depend on the locale. It's always ".". See the documentation. Also, you shouldn't catch exception, print the stack trace and then carry on. If you don't know what to do with an exception, don't catch it at all. The JVM will handle it in a better way.

Comment: So regardless of Locale, the actual Number related objects all use the '.' notation? And Locale only plays a part with formatting like with the NumberFormat object?

Comment: Yes, for example `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY).format(1.23)` will return "1,23".

Comment: Another way to use Locale is `String.format(Locale.ITALY, "%.6f", 1.23)` (gives 1,230000)

Comment: That actually helps as I thought the Locale affected the actual Numeric value. If I am following, it seems the Locale only affects how the number is shown as a String format and not necessarily as a number.

Comment: The numeric value has no concept of Locale or notation.  It is just numbers (zeros and ones representing a number). It's only when you format a number as a String that Locale and notation has any meaning.

Comment: @UnhandledException You said "I thought the Locale affected the actual Numeric value". I'm not sure what that means but `double` and it's box dual `Double` don't use a decimal point internally. The value is packed into 64 bits (8 bytes). So yes. Locale is how it's formatted and then as commented some `toString()` methods don't use the locale.